# Django Connect to MS SQL along side postgres

Tags: python, sql, django, pyodbc

I have a standard django setup using postgres, but I also want to access data from a mssql database. I have installed pyodbc and was in the process of installing django-pyodbc but the instructions tell me how to make the mssql the default database which is not what I want.

I was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction. It doesnt bother me if the method bypasses django and just uses Python to retrieve the data

Cheers,

JJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Django 1.2 or later, you can use Django's [built-in multi-database support](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/multi-db/). You can follow the `django-pyodbc` directions, and give your database a name other than `'default'`.